# How to bind form based actions like 'Save' to designated Java classes mentioned in xwork in Confluence

Tags: plugins, customization, velocity, confluence

I have made some significant progress in my customization efforst thanks to your help and looking forward to move forward similarly.
I have created the custom tab in the 'Advanced' tab and it now looks like [this](http://imageshack.us/f/809/newpageg.png/). 
I have been able to add a text field as well as a 'Save' button. I actually followed the 'Edit Space Details' option and took two of its form elements to achieve the output.
This is how my VM looks now.

```
  ##requireResource("confluence.web.resources:space-admin")
 <html>
   <head>
       <title>Freeway Project Creation</title>
      <meta name="decorator" content="atl.general" />   
   </head>

    <content tag="key">$action.space.key</content>

  <body>    

   #applyDecorator("root")
     #decoratorParam("helper" $action.helper)
     #decoratorParam("context" "space-administration")
     #decoratorParam("mode" "view-space-administration")

    #applyDecorator ("root")
     #decoratorParam ("context" "spaceadminpanel")
     #decoratorParam ("selection" "add-fpc-label-action-web-ui")
     #decoratorParam ("title" $action.getText("action.name"))
     #decoratorParam ("selectedTab" "admin")
     #decoratorParam("helper" $action.helper) 


      <div >
            <table width="95%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>
              <form name="editspace" method="POST" >

        #bodytag( "TextField" "label='space-name'" "name='name'" "size=40" )
        #param ("labelwidth" "100")
        #param ("tdcolor" "f0f0f0")
        #end

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                  #tag( "Submit" "name='confirm'" "value='update.name'" "theme='notable'" )
                #tag( "Submit" "name='cancel'" "value='cancel.name'" "theme='notable'" )
               </td>
             </tr>

        </form>
     </table>
  </div>



    #end
   #end    
  </body>
 </html>
```

I would like to understand how this interaction with my JAVA class will result in the output like. For eg: I will enter the name in the text box for name and hit save and on a resulting page it must display the name entered.

As of now my designated java class looks like this.

```
  package com.atlassian.myorg;

 import com.atlassian.confluence.core.ConfluenceActionSupport;
 import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.AbstractPage;
 import com.atlassian.confluence.pages.actions.PageAware;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork.Action;

 /**
   * The simplest action possible
 */
 public class FreewayProjectAction extends ConfluenceActionSupport 
  {
     @Override
      public String execute() throws Exception
   {
       return Action.SUCCESS;
  }

 }
```

So I have 3 questions:

1. The 'Edit Space Details' shows the following URL 'http://localhost:1990/confluence/spaces/doeditspace.action?key=LBTEST' when i mouse over the 'Save' button. I am assuming that its governing Java class is EditSpaceDetails. So is the doEdit() method  (see [here](http://imageshack.us/f/542/decompdoedit.png/) )inside that class that swings into action when we try to save the edit action of the space ? Can i get to see the xml that has this mapping specifically for this edit space details action? Is my assumptin correct ?
2. In order to have such a functionality i have mentioned earlier i.e. displaying the name entered in my custom page as detailed above what will be the changes required in my Java class.
3. In the page i have just customised there is the text box and the label is 'Name' . Should i use a different xml so that i can provide my custom label like "Project Name" ?

Please do kindly advice me on the same.

Thanks 
Angie

Answer (score 1):

to answer your first question - you're able to get a deeper insight into the xwork action mappings, interceptors and possible result types if you're taking a look at *confluence-core/confluence/src/etc/java/xwork.xml*.

The following example is the corresponding mapping for your "doeditspace.action":

```
<action name="doeditspace" class="com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.actions.EditSpaceAction" method="doEdit">
    <param name="RequireSecurityToken">true</param>
    <result name="error" type="velocity">/spaces/editspace.vm</result>
    <result name="input" type="velocity">/spaces/editspace.vm</result>
    <result name="cancel" type="redirect">viewspacedetails.action?key=${key}</result>
    <result name="success" type="redirect">viewspacedetails.action?key=${key}</result>
</action>
```

So if the return value from your *execute* method is *ActionType.SUCCESS* or "*success*", the request will be redirected to the *viewspacedetails* action.

Additional information is documented in the Atlassian Developer Website: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/XWork-WebWork+Module